# Magento 1 - Error Log file is not createed

Tags: error-log

To get error log file I enable on this menu

```
Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes
```

and create `/var/log` folder and set the permission `777`

When I got this error page

> There has been an error processing your request
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1337641918483

There is no file on the var/log folder

Can I know the reason why the error log file is not created and how to solver?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you see an error like this it is a complete application failure - which will actually be logged by corresponding number to `/var/report/`

(Per comments) if this dir doesn't exist try to set 777 perms recursively on var a la `chmod -R 777 var/`

Comment: Thanks! I just found there is no file in /var/report/ folder too Can I know where I can find or reason..?

Comment: Likely php does not have permission to write to var and var/report. If php runs as webserver user, try chmod -R 777 var/ to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see these errors directly on the page, add

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true
```

to the top of your .htaccess file. You will get the full error directly through the browser, instead of having to get the file from var/report.

**Note::** Remove SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true from .htaccess before you go live!

The most concise and comprehensive post I have seen on Magento debugging, and a great resource, is here: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the fault is with permissions of the folder and the files within.

Sometimes when Magento create a folder it doesn't add the correct permissions to that folder "As in user / owner permissions" not just 777.

You need to:

1. Login via SSH as root and type the following

chown accountuser.accountuser /home/accountuser/public_html/var/report

Or

chown accountuser.accountuser /home/accountuser/public_html/var/report* "But be very careful with the "*" I'd personally do it just for the last few as getting it wrong will cause you a world of pain.

2. Get your host to sort it out and then happy days

Answer (score 1):

In my case just the sub directory "log" was not owned by the running apache user.

**My apache user is bitnami:daemon...**

So for me the solution was:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon var/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Magento 1, then there's an option to look after the Magento logs. When it comes to Magento 2 there isn't any :/ And I'mn not going to recommend you to work on Magento 1 as it's going to be EOL for version 1 this year.

So, what you can do is:

SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true

If you want to see these errors directly on the page.

Second is hosting provider that can also help with that. As I know one of the hosting provider who helps me to track the server logs like Appache and NGINX.